# Using qsort() to sort array of struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I need to sort an array consisting of `struct` pointers based on the values stored in the `struct`. The code is:

```
typedef unsigned int word;
typedef struct xid { word w[5]; } xid;
typedef xid *list;

int comparexid(xid *id1, xid *id2);
static int quicksort(list *base, size_t narray, size_t size, int(*compare)(const void *, const void *));


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static list addr[MAXENTRIES];
    int nlist;

    // Fill addr
    quicksort((list *)&addr[0], nlist, sizeof(list), comparexid);
}

int comparexid(xid *id1, xid *id2)
{
    int cmp;
    cmp = memcmp(id1, id2, 20);

    if (cmp > 0)
            return 1;
    else if (cmp < 0)
            return -1;
    else
            return 0;
}

static int quicksort(list *base, size_t narray, size_t size, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *))
{
    // Print original
    qsort(&base[0], narray, size, compare);
    // Print sorted
}
```

The `structs` that are pointed to by `addr` are not sorted correctly.

The sample input (printed in base 16) of 9 such `structs` and the output are as follows:

Input:

```
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567898
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567897
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567896
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567895
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567894
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567893
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567892
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567891
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567890
```

Output:

```
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567892
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567891
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567898
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567890
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567897
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567896
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567895
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567894
b23456789ab23456789ab23456789ab234567893
```

Comment: In `comparexid`, the parameters should be of type `xid **`, since `qsort` is going to pass the address of a pointer. (To be pedantically correct, the parameters should be of type `const void *`, and you should cast them to `const xid **` in the body of the function.)

Comment: Also note that big-endian unsigned integers can be compared with `memcmp()`; I don't think either little-endian or signed integers can be reliably compared with `memcmp()` and end up with a comparison in numeric order.  You're using `unsigned int`; that's good.  It isn't clear whether you're on a big-endian or little-endian machine.

Comment: You code does not compile and has a lot of errors. Post a minimal correct complete example!